# Is there a statistics method similar to Anova for groups of data that change over time (or other independent variable)?

Tags: time-series, anova, standard-deviation, matlab, linear

My dependent variable (temperature), is time dependent (time groups 1-8, each 15 minutes apart). 5 different plants were measured. I want to know if there is a significant difference between the plants. I do not think Anova is a good test, as the temperature increases over time. (Anova says p=0.3642 (no difference in groups)).

[image]

I feel that there should be something for this problem, but I am not sure how to phrase it.

Comment: You will find useful information by searching on this site for mixed-effect models (random intercept and/or slope), or repeated or time-dependent measures. Basically, you need to account for multiple observations collected on the same plant over time, which implies some form of within-unit correlation.

Comment: See answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197607/how-to-test-difference-between-times-series-does-time-series-anova-exist .